# How can I print more than one fields resulting from a query?

Tags: go

I am trying to learn how to use the `database/sql` package with [go-sql-driver](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/). I wrote the following simple program and it works, but I could not figure out how to print more than one fields.

The database `wiki1` has three fields, `id`, `title` and `body`. I query for "title1" which is one of the values but I want to print the values for "title" and "body". How do I this?

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {


    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:Password1@/wiki1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    st, err := db.Prepare("SELECT title FROM page WHERE title=?")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    rows, err := st.Query("title1")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var title, body string
        if err := rows.Scan(&title); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%s\n", title)
    }
    if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read the `body` and the `title` instead of just the `title`, first change the statement.

Change

```
st, err := db.Prepare("SELECT title FROM page WHERE title=?")
```

to

```
st, err := db.Prepare("SELECT body, title FROM page WHERE title=?")
```

Then change the reading. Change

```
    var title, body string
    if err := rows.Scan(&title); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

to

```
    var title, body string
    if err := rows.Scan(&body, &title); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

This reads both columns.

To print the fields, you can do

```
fmt.Printf("title: %s\nbody: %s\n", title, body)
```

You'll find more details regarding querying using database/sql, read this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353679/whats-the-recommended-way-to-connect-to-mysql-from-go).

Comment: Thank you, @dystroy! I noticed also that the order of column names in `SELECT` must match the order of columns in the database.

Comment: No, the order of column in the select doesn't have to match the one of the database, normally. But the order in the select must match the order of the `scan`.