# fetch database using golang

Tags: mysql, go

I have few functions to connect to a database and fetch results. My question is why fetch not working?

My database structure looks like

[image: database structure]

My main.go code is

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type maintable struct {
    Id          int
    Location    string
    Picname     string
    Malefemale  string
    Name        string
    Country     string
    Connections int
}

func dbConn() (db *sql.DB) {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/test_db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    return db
}

var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("form/*"))

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := dbConn()
    selDB, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM main_table ORDER BY user_id DESC")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer selDB.Close()
    maint := maintable{}
    res := []maintable{}
    for selDB.Next() {
        var id, connections int
        var name, country, location, picname, malefemale string
        err = selDB.Scan(&id, &name, &country, &location, &picname, &malefemale, &connections)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        maint.Id = id
        maint.Name = name
        maint.Country = country
        maint.Location = location
        maint.Picname = picname
        maint.Malefemale = malefemale
        maint.Connections = connections
        res = append(res, maint)
    }
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "Index", res)
    defer db.Close()
}

func Show(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db := dbConn()
    nID := r.URL.Query().Get("user_id")
    selDB, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE user_id=?", nID)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    maint := maintable{}
    for selDB.Next() {
        var id, connections int
        var name, country, location, picname, malefemale string
        err = selDB.Scan(&id, &name, &country, &location, &picname, &malefemale, &connections)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        maint.Id = id
        maint.Name = name
        maint.Country = country
        maint.Location = location
        maint.Picname = picname
        maint.Malefemale = malefemale
        maint.Connections = connections
    }
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "Show", maint)
    defer db.Close()
}

    log.Println("Server started on: http://localhost:3000")
    http.HandleFunc("/", Index)
    http.HandleFunc("/show", Show)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

And my show.tmpl code is looks like

```
{{ define "Show" }}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Golang Mysql Curd Example</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Golang Mysql Curd Example</h1>   
<a href="/">HOME</a> | 
<a href="/new">NEW</a>
    <h2> Register {{ .Id }} </h2>
      <p>Name: {{ .Name }}</p>
      <p>Picture name:  {{ .Picname }}</p>
      <p>Picture location:  {{ .Location }}</p>
      <p>Gender:  {{ .Malefemale }}</p>
<p>Country:  {{ .Country }}</p>
<p>User connections:  {{ .Connections }}</p>
      <br /> <a href="/edit?user_id={{ .Id }}">Edit</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

Do I need create array and append all results to array? Is there other way to display multi rows?

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11357116/3824876

Comment: What do you intend with "fetch is not working"?